# Doctrine ORM select articles by list of tags

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tags, many-to-many, dql

I have a `Webinar` entity that is connected to `Tag`'s with many-to-many association.

I want to fetch webinars by the list of tags, so the webinar must have ALL the tags in the list to appear in the result.

And I have the following code to query it:

```php
$tags = [1, 2];

// Base query.
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('W, VR, AR, T')
    ->from('Model:Webinar',     'W')
    ->leftJoin('W.videoRecord', 'VR')
    ->leftJoin('W.audioRecord', 'AR')
    ->leftJoin('W.tags',        'T')
;

// Tags query.
if (isset($tags)) {
    $builder
        ->andWhere('T.id IN (:tags)')
        ->setParameter('tags', $tags)
    ;
}

// Other conditions.
// ...

// Issuing the query.
return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This query will give me all webinars that have at least one tag in the list (OR), but I want it to have all tags in the list (AND).

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856173/doctrine-2-manytomany-relation-selecting-entity-with-and). But looks like I have a more complex example and I'm not sure how to re-write my code to enable the correct behavior, I have other joined entities and additional conditions. Is it possible to isolate this behavior in a single block without breaking the whole query and other conditionals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not being able to use both aggregations and fetching in a single query so I decided to split it in two.

By using first query I will apply all necessary conditions in order to receive the list of webinar IDs and by using a second query I will fetch the object graph for these IDs.

Here's the complete example:

```php
// I. Making the first query to fetch only webinar IDs.

// Base query.
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('W.id')
    ->from('Model:Webinar', 'W')
    ->orderBy('W.' . $sort, $order)
;

// Selected tags condition.
if (is_array($criteria['tags']) && count($criteria['tags']) > 0) {
    $builder
        ->innerJoin('W.tags', 'T', 'WITH', 'T.id IN (:tags)')
        ->setParameter('tags', $criteria['tags'])
        ->groupBy('W.id')
        ->having('COUNT(T.id) = :tags_count')
        ->setParameter('tags_count', count($criteria['tags']))
    ;
}

// Any additional conditions
// ...

// Building the list of webinar IDs.
$ids = [];
foreach ($builder->getQuery()->getScalarResult() as $record) {
    $ids[] = $record['id'];
}

// II. And now selecting complete object graph for specified webinar IDs.

// Base query.
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('W, VR, AR, T')
    ->from('Model:Webinar',       'W')
    ->leftJoin('W.videoRecord',   'VR')
    ->leftJoin('W.audioRecord',   'AR')
    ->leftJoin('W.tags',          'T')
    ->where('W.id IN (:ids)')
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
;

// Issuing the query.
return $builder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I hope it will help someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is how sql's `IN` clause works, it takes all rows with `ANY` of items in `IN` list. You must do something similar like in answer you provided, so in your case your query would look like:

```
// Base query.
$builder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('W, VR, AR, T')
    ->from('Model:Webinar',     'W')
    ->leftJoin('W.videoRecord', 'VR')
    ->leftJoin('W.audioRecord', 'AR')
    ->leftJoin('W.tags',        'T')
;

// Tags query.
if (isset($tags)) {
    $builder
        ->andWhere('T.id IN (:tags)')
        ->setParameter('tags', $tags)
    ;


    $builder->groupBy('T.id')
        ->having("COUNT(DISTINCT T.id) = :count")
        ->setParameter("count", count($tags));
}
```

This should work correctly I guess

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Tomasz! I've tried something similar, I'm getting the following exception: `ERROR: column "w0_.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.